# Validate one field mysql laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, validation, laravel, laravel-5

I intend to use in my backend a form of validation as prestashop have but I'm not thinking the way I am right to perform this task.

I intend it to be so my validation.

[image]

**My table**

```
ID|Id_workshop|videos|validate
```

**My index code**

For now I'm just trying to validate this when inactive to active.I intend to activate the database becomes 1 instead of continuing to the value 0.

```
    @if ($video->validate == 1) 
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <a href="{{URL::to('backend/workshops/validate/'.$video->id) }}">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
                        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                    </button>
                </a>
            </td>
    @else 
        {!! Form::open(array('url' => 'backend/workshops/validate/{{$video->id}}', 'id' => 'form', 'name' => 'ValidateWorkshop', 'role' => 'form', 'class' => 'form-signin'))!!}
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $video->id }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="validate" value="{{ $video->validate }}">

            <td style="text-align: center;">
                    {!! Form::submit('X', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
            </td>       
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    @endif
```

**My controller**

```
    public function ValidateWorkshop($id) {
        $validate = Input::except('_token'); 
        $validate = Input::get('id');
        $validation = Validator::make($validate, Videos::$validate); 
        if ($validation->passes()) {
            if($user = Videos::find($validate['id'])) {
                $user -> update($validate); 
            }
        Session::flash('validate_workshop', 'O workshop foi validado'); 
        return Redirect::to('backend/workshops'); 
        } else { 
            return Redirect::to('backend/workshops')->withInput()->withErrors($validation); 
        }           
    }
```

**My route**

```
Route::post('backend/workshops/validate/{id}','BackendControlador@ValidateWorkshop');
```

**My model**

```
public static $validate = array(
        'validar' =>  'int',
        );
```

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution in the controller**

I used a predefined function of laravel eloquent orm to be able to do the update.
The only parameter we need to do is give the ID.

```
    public function ValidarWorkshop($id) {
        $validar = Input::get('validar');
        $id = Input::get('id');
        if ($validar == 0) {
            $validar = Videos::find($id);
            $validar->validar = '1';
            $validar->save();                                                       
            Session::flash('workshop', 'Workshop inserido com sucesso'); 
            return Redirect::to('backend/workshops');               
        }
    }
```